# How do I save a list to a pickle file in a temporary directory and pass that file into a function?

Tags: python, directory, save, dropbox, pickle

The issue is that I'm pulling data from one source and I want to save it to dropbox as a pickle file. I can't save it in a directory, because I'm running the code on a server (iron.io).

```
import tempfile
import pickle


def SFDCDropboxSync(Data):
   f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
   pickle.dump(Data,open(f,'wb'))

   client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
   client.put_file(filename, f)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump/SFDCDropboxUpload.py", line 38, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump/SFDCDropboxUpload.py", line 31, in main
    print SFDCDropboxUploadDownload().SFDCDropboxSync(lst)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump/SFDCDropboxUpload.py", line 26, in SFDCDropboxSync
    pkl = self.SaveListtoPickle(lst)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump/SFDCDropboxUpload.py", line 20, in SaveListtoPickle
    pickle.dump(lst,open(f,'wb')) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found [Finished in 0.7s with exit code 1] [shell_cmd: python -u "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump/SFDCDropboxUpload.py"] [dir: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/RecurringDataDump] [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Have you attempted to dump without the `b` flag? `pickle.dump(lst,open(f,'w'))`

Comment: Program and traceback don't match... but it looks like Data (or lst?) isn't a pickable object. So, what are you passing in?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the NamedTemporaryFile f is not a string. It is a file object, similar to the output of open(file_path).

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile): This file-like object can be used in a with statement, just like a normal file.

If you want to path to the created file, use tmp_file.name

For example, this works: (tested on python 3.6.2)

```
def SFDCDropboxSync(Data):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
        pickle.dump(Data, tmp_file)
        tmp_file.flush()

        print(pickle.load(open(tmp_file.name, 'rb')))
```

This will delete the file when it exits the while (file closes).

**Warning for Windows**: you might have trouble reading the file while it is open. Instead, use something similar to this:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
    pickle.dump(Data, open(tmp_file.name, 'wb'))
    tmp_filename = tmp_file.name

pickle.load(open(tmp_filename, 'rb'))
os.remove(tmp_filename)
```

Comment: use file.seek(0) and you can just use a normal tempfile its faster i guess than reopening the file

Comment: This will delete the file when it exits the _with_.

Comment: @user39430 you probably missed the `delete=False`